# Apple Sandbox IAP transactions missing from verifyReceipt in_app and latest_receipt_info

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an app where I've been offering auto renewable in-app-subscriptions for a while without problems. Now I'm trying to add in-app-purchases, which also works, but now I experienced "ghost transactions" when trying to verify the receipt in the backend.

I have non-consumable products: `product1`, `product2`, `product3` and auto-renewable subscriptions: `subscriptionmonthly`, `subscriptionyearly`

I'm using a sandbox testing user. I purchased `product1`, `product2` and `subscriptionmonthly`.

What I do is that I run `SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions` in the app and then I log all the transactions. I get back `subscriptionmonthly`, `product1` and `product2` as expected.

All transactions have *the same receipt data*, which I send to the [verifyReceipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) (sandbox) endpoint. I get back a valid JSON response and I see `subscriptionmonthly`, `product1` and `product2` as expected inside the response.

**Two days later** I do the same and I still get back `subscriptionmonthly`, `product1` and `product2` in the app. When I send the receipt to `verifyReceipt` I get a valid JSON response again. Inside `in_app` and `latest_receipt_info` I can see `subscriptionmonthly`, **however I do not see the `product1` or `product2`, so they have somehow vanished.** I tried to purchase `product1` in the app again, and the IAP purchase dialog says that **you've already purchased this product**. If I press OK and take the receipt again and send to `verifyReceipt`, there is still no `product1` in the response. If I now purchase another product `product3`, and send the receipt to `verifyReceipt`, I correctly get `product3` back in the response, but still no `product1` or `product2`.

Is there any way I could be doing something wrong here, or is this just a known issue with the Sandbox that we cannot really trust what `verifyReceipt` gives us here?

Note that I'm using [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) however I believe it shouldn't matter because in the app I do see all the transactions.